# My current code isn’t running properly in MS Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I am working on a project for the office today and I’m running into a bit of a stumble today on it. My code is properly debugged but it when ran it ignores all the parameters I set up and becomes smashed all together in a one line executable (if that makes sense). Here’s the prompt and what I have so far:

“A business needs to calculate the bonus points for sales representatives. The bonus points are based on how much each sales representative sold the year.

Write a program to prompt the user to enter the sales amount for a sales representative. Include different functions for each group of Sales representatives.

Display the bonus points as integers.

Please see the table showing the Groups, Sales, and Bonus points:

Groups Sales Bonus points:

A $0 - $100, 000 500 points

$100, 001 - $1,000,000 1, 500 points

B $1,000,001 - $2,000, 000 2,000 points

$2,000,001 - $3,000, 000 2, 500 points

C $3,000,001 - $4,000, 000 3, 000 points

$4,000,001 and over 5, 000 points

Input Validation: Do not accept negative numbers for sales.”

And here’s what I have tried so far:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
    
float salesamounts; //sales made 
int username; // Sales rep name
    
int main()
{
    cout << “Please enter your sales made for the year: $”
    cin >> salesamounts;
    cout << endl;

    // exception on program
    if (salesamounts <= -1);
    {
        if (salesamounts <= -1);
            cout << “Value cannot be negative. Please input again.”
    }
    
    // Group A placement
    for (;salesamount <= 100000;)
    {
        if ((salesamounts <= 100000) 
        cout << “Congratulations! You earned 500 Bonus Points!”
    
        break;
    {
    
    for (; salesamounts > 100001 < 1000000;)
    { 
        if ((salesamounts > 100001 < 1000000));
            cout << “Congrats! 10000 Bonus Points have been credited to you!”
    
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format your code. You can find formatting help on the "Edit Question" page: `(?) => 'Code'`. Formatting makes it easier for others to read and offer suggestions.

Comment: `if (salesamounts <= -1);` is the same as `if (salesamounts <= -1) { /* empty body of if statement */ }` Drop the semicolon at the end.

Comment: Note: your quotes got mauled by whatever you types this in.

Comment: `when ran` The posted code is several steps away from compiling, let alone running.

Comment: I tossed the code into a formatter to quickly indent it and it revealed a few mistakes. Use a regular indentation scheme, I use [Allman style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Allman_style), and it'll show you mistakes as you make them. Because some of the mistakes probably ARE the bug you're hunting, I'm not updating the code, but here's a hint: make sure you really want all of the semicolons you're using.

Comment: this is a homework question if I've ever seen one

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement, you could use `if-elseif-else` to judge each group of Sales representatives, which is like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   double salesamounts; //sales made 

   int username; // Sales rep name

   cout << "Please enter your sales made for the year : $" << endl;

   
   while (cin >> salesamounts) {
          // exception on program
          if (salesamounts < 0.0) {
                 cout << "Value cannot be negative.Please input again." << endl;
          }

          //judge salesamounts
          else if (salesamounts>0.0 && salesamounts <= 100000.0) {
                 cout << "Congratulations!You earned 500 Bonus Points!" << endl;
          }
          else if (salesamounts > 100000.0 && salesamounts <= 1000000.0) {
                 cout << "Congrats!1500 Bonus Points have been credited to you!" << endl;
          }
          else if (salesamounts > 1000000.0 && salesamounts <= 2000000.0) {
                 cout << "Congrats!2,000 Bonus Points have been credited to you!" << endl;
          }
          else if (salesamounts > 2000000.0 && salesamounts <= 3000000.0) {
                 cout << "Congrats!2,500 Bonus Points have been credited to you!" << endl;
          }
          else if (salesamounts > 3000000.0 && salesamounts <= 4000000.0) {
                 cout << "Congrats!3,000 Bonus Points have been credited to you!" << endl;
          }
          else if (salesamounts > 4000000.0 ) {
                 cout << "Congrats!5,000 Bonus Points have been credited to you!" << endl;
          }
          else {
                 break;
          }
     }
}
```

By the way, you could also use [switch statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/switch-statement-cpp?view=vs-2019) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You did the input part almost correctly, but after that you confused the `if-else-if` part with `for` loops.

When taking the user input, you can use a while loop to check whether the value is negative or not. This will make the program to prompt the user to enter a value again if the entered value does not match the criteria:

```
float salesamounts;
cout<<"Enter the sales amounts for the year:";   //the program will prompt the user initially
cin>>salesamounts;   //user inputs the value here
while(salesamounts<0)   //this line checks if the value is negative, if yes, it'll continue running this block till the value is non-negative
{
    cout<<"Negative numbers not allowed. Please enter again: ";   //Suppose the value is negative. Then the program will display this line and prompt the user to enter again
    cin>>salesamounts;   //user enters the value again
}
```

The next step in your program is to then check the user input and make the program act accordingly. The `if-else` statement will do that perfectly:

```
if (salesamount<=100000)   //checks the value. If this is true, then then the following line will run. Else, the program will move to the next check.
cout<<"Bonus point is 500";   //displays the output if the above condition is correct
else if (salesamount<=1000000)   //second check
cout<<"Bonus point is 1500";   //displays if the second condition is true
.
.
.
else
cout<<"Bonus point is 5000";
```

and so on.

Just to clarify, a **loop** is used only when you want a particular block of code to run repeatedly, whereas, to check or compare two values, you use the **if-else** statement.

**Note that** I've not written the second check as `if (salesamounts>=100001 && salesamounts<=1000000)` and also, I gave the last check as only `else`, not `else if`.